# How to make some jsonb field's value to a json array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql

Here is a table:

```
create table test(
  fjson jsonb
);
```

then insert some value:

```
insert into test values
('{"name":"A"}'::jsonb),
('{"name":"B"}'::jsonb),
('{"name":"C"}'::jsonb);
```

I want to get a json array like below:

```
[
  {"name":"A"},
  {"name":"B"},
  {"name":"C"}
]
```

How to write the SQL?

Thanks.

Problem solved. thanks

```
do $$ declare
    jdata jsonb;
begin
    create temp table test(
      fjson jsonb
    ) on commit drop;
    
    insert into test values
    ('{"name":"A"}'::jsonb),
    ('{"name":"B"}'::jsonb),
    ('{"name":"C"}'::jsonb);
    
    select (select jsonb_agg(fjson) from test) into jdata;
    raise notice '%',jdata;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(fjson) from test
```

to get a jsonb array, or

```
SELECT array_agg(fjson) from test
```

to get a native pg array.